# Вывод списка друзей laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php7, laravel5

есть таблица друзей

```
user | friend | status
```

как вывести список друзей, сейчас вывожу только тех, кого я добавил, но не выводятся те которые меня добавили

```
$friends = DB::table('friends')
           ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'friends.friend')
           ->leftJoin('user_attributes', 'user_attributes.user_id', 'friends.friend')
           ->select('users.name', 'users.id', 'user_attributes.avatar', 'users.lastonline', 'users.id')
           ->where('friends.status', '>', 1)
           ->where('friends.user', Auth::user()->id)
           ->orderBy('friends.id', 'asc')->get();
```

мой id 14 значит у меня нужно вывести 20 и 15 друзей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне записать в ларавел что-то типа такого

```
SELECT `friend` f FROM `friends` WHERE `status` > 1 and `user`=14
UNION
SELECT `user` f FROM `friends` WHERE `status` > 1 and `friend`=14
```

Answer (score 1):

поправьте плз, если я сделал не так

```
$friendsi = DB::table('friends')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'friends.friend')
                ->leftJoin('user_attributes', 'user_attributes.user_id', 'friends.friend')
                ->select('users.name', 'user_attributes.avatar', 'users.lastonline', 'users.id as id')
                ->where('friends.status', '>', 1)
                ->where('friends.user', Auth::user()->id);

            $friends = DB::table('friends')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'friends.user')
                ->leftJoin('user_attributes', 'user_attributes.user_id', 'friends.user')
                ->select('users.name', 'user_attributes.avatar', 'users.lastonline', 'users.id as id')
                ->where('friends.friend', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('friends.status', '>', 1)
                ->union($friendsi)
                ->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
        }
```